# Deactivate the drag-and-drop feature

Tags: python, tkinter, unbind

```
def drag_and_drop(self):
    """
    Method allowing to drag and drop a pawn
    """
    if self.game.onOff.get() == 1:
       self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}
       self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.drag_beg)
       self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.drag_end)
       self.tag_bind("piece", "<B1-Motion>", self.drag)
    else:
       do_Something()

def drag_beg(self, event):
    """Begining drag of an object"""
    # record the item and its location
    self._drag_data["item"] = self.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
    self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
    self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

def drag_end(self, event):
    """End drag of an object"""
    # reset the drag information
    self._drag_data["item"] = None
    self._drag_data["x"] = 0
    self._drag_data["y"] = 0

def drag(self, event):
    """Handle dragging of an object"""
    # compute how much the mouse has moved
    delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
    delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]
    # move the object the appropriate amount
    self.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
    # record the new position
    self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
    self._drag_data["y"] = event.y
```

The code above allows me to drag and drop a pawn in a checkerboard. The `drag_and_drop` function is associated with a checkbutton (i.e. with tkinter). When I check the box in my interface, the drag and drop is activated. When I unchecked the box, I would like to bring back the old setup, i.e. I click once on a case source and I click a second time target case to move the pawn to the new case. I think I have to implement the method `do_Something()` to deactivate the drag-and-drop feature? How can I do that?

When I check the box, the drag-and-drop is very well activated, but when I unchecked the box, the function drag-and-drop is still activated. I have not found a way to deactivated it.

**UPDATE**

Can I unbind it this way?

```
self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonPress-1>")
self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonRelease-1>")
self.tag_bind("piece", "<B1-Motion>")
```

Comment: Can you not simply add an `if (drag_disabled): return` statement at the beginning of each event handler to simply return instead of processing the event?  You have to define that flag in a class or globally.

Comment: @RufusVS Are you up make a full answer? So far when I check the box, the drag-and-drop is very well activated, but when I unchecked the box, the function drag-and-drop is still activated. I have not found a way to deactivated it so far.

Comment: @RufusVS Changing `do_Something()` by `return` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: After looking more closely, it looks like you are looking to un-bind the events.  I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I have modified the question.  I think I can use `tag_unbind`, but I am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of switching on and off the drag and drop feature.

1. As asked by the OP, it is possible to unbind the tag bindings:
   The use of `tag_unbind` is pretty straightforward: `.tag_unbind(<tag>, <sequence>)` will unbind all bindings to the given sequence for items with given tag. In this case:

   ```
   def drag_and_drop(self):
       """
       Method allowing to drag and drop a pawn
       """
       if self.game.onOff.get() == 1:
          self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}
          self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.drag_beg)
          self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.drag_end)
          self.tag_bind("piece", "<B1-Motion>", self.drag)
       else:
          self.tag_unbind("piece", "<ButtonPress-1>")
          self.tag_unbind("piece", "<ButtonRelease-1>")
          self.tag_unbind("piece", "<B1-Motion>")
   ```

   Below is a full example:

   ```
   import tkinter as tk

   class Board(tk.Canvas):
       def __init__(self, master, drag_enabled, **kw):
           tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, **kw)
           self.drag_enabled = drag_enabled
           self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}
           self.create_oval(10, 10, 50, 50, fill='white', tags='piece')

       def drag_and_drop(self):
           """
           Method allowing to drag and drop a pawn
           """
           if self.drag_enabled.get():
               self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}
               self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.drag_beg)
               self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.drag_end)
               self.tag_bind("piece", "<B1-Motion>", self.drag)
           else:
               self.tag_unbind("piece", "<ButtonPress-1>")
               self.tag_unbind("piece", "<ButtonRelease-1>")
               self.tag_unbind("piece", "<B1-Motion>")

       def drag_beg(self, event):
           """Begining drag of an object"""
           # record the item and its location
           self._drag_data["item"] = self.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
           self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
           self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

       def drag_end(self, event):
           """End drag of an object"""
           # reset the drag information
           self._drag_data["item"] = None
           self._drag_data["x"] = 0
           self._drag_data["y"] = 0

       def drag(self, event):
           """Handle dragging of an object"""
           # compute how much the mouse has moved
           delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
           delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]
           # move the object the appropriate amount
           self.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
           # record the new position
           self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
           self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

   root = tk.Tk()
   drag_enabled = tk.BooleanVar(root)
   board = Board(root, drag_enabled)
   tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Enable drag', variable=drag_enabled,
                  command=board.drag_and_drop).pack(side='bottom')
   board.pack()
   root.mainloop()
   ```
2. As suggested in the comments, it is possible to check whether drag and drop is activated inside the functions called by the bindings and return without doing anything if it is disabled. Something like:

   ```
    def <drag function>(self, event):
        if self.drag_enabled.get():
             # drag and drop actions
   ```

   In this case, the `drag_and_drop()` function is not needed and can be put into the initialization of the board:

   ```
    import tkinter as tk

    class Board(tk.Canvas):
        def __init__(self, master, drag_enabled, **kw):
            tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, **kw)
            self.drag_enabled = drag_enabled
            self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}
            self.create_oval(10, 10, 50, 50, fill='white', tags='piece')

            self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}
            self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.drag_beg)
            self.tag_bind("piece", "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.drag_end)
            self.tag_bind("piece", "<B1-Motion>", self.drag)

        def drag_beg(self, event):
            """Begining drag of an object"""
            # record the item and its location
            if self.drag_enabled.get():
                self._drag_data["item"] = self.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
                self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
                self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

        def drag_end(self, event):
            """End drag of an object"""
            # reset the drag information
            self._drag_data["item"] = None
            self._drag_data["x"] = 0
            self._drag_data["y"] = 0

        def drag(self, event):
            """Handle dragging of an object"""
            # compute how much the mouse has moved
            if self.drag_enabled.get():
                delta_x = event.x - self._drag_data["x"]
                delta_y = event.y - self._drag_data["y"]
                # move the object the appropriate amount
                self.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
                # record the new position
                self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
                self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

    root = tk.Tk()
    drag_enabled = tk.BooleanVar(root)
    b = Board(root, drag_enabled)
    tk.Checkbutton(root, text='Enable drag', variable=drag_enabled).pack(side='bottom')
    b.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
   ```